# Link external resource in sitecore 9.3 media library

Tags: media-library, pdf

We have a Sitecore 9.3 instance running a site. Our problem is that resources uploaded on the Media Library occupy too much disk space. We want to create a custom media library object that links to a media/pdf/etc directly on the web without having to save the file on the SQL blob storage.

I've searched a lot on the web and haven't found a proper solution to this.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Replacing SQL blob storage with Azure Blob Storage will work for you? https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/en/enable-the-azure-blob-storage-module-for-sitecore-blobs.html

Comment: no, we need to point directly on a web resource (i.e.) a pdf, thanks for your reply!

Comment: Not sure that there is a way to do that, if database size is what is concerns you, is saving the pdf to the file system an option?

Comment: So why try to do this with Media Library? Just create an item template with name, url, and so on, and use that.

Comment: @AJ- no...now i'm tryng to read in a sample app a dummy pdf file online and return a MediaStream instead of a Stream..(by a GetResponseByStream), with no luck